# What is the difference between Markovian queuing models and non-Markovian queuing models?

Tags: stochastic-processes, markov-process

What is the difference between Markovian queuing models and non-Markovian queuing models?

What is the difference between Markovian queuing models and non-Markovian queuing models?

I know that the Markovian queuing models have times of arrival and service that follow a Poisson distribution and consequently non-Markovians are those that do not have the Poisson distribution in both times. Is there any other difference?

Thanks

Comment: *Markovian* will mean what may happen in the future can depend on the current position, but given that then not on the past - another word is *memoryless*; by contrast *non-Markovian* will mean that in addition to the effect of the current position, previous positions may also have an impact.